# How to rate a statistical variable?

Tags: statistics

I have lots of data and I'm trying to attach a rating to each of the variables depending on how closely the correlate with any subgroups.

For example, suppose I have a bunch of people and they are separated into two groups that just happen to correlate with the larger shoe sizes in one and the smaller in the other, how would I, without looking by hand, find that correlation?

One way that seems to give an indication is to compare the standard deviation across the group and across the whole corpus, and divide the second by the first indicating a reverse correlation.

But the issue is this obviously has some issues, but I have no idea where to look or what this area would be (obviously statistics, but what subtopic?) References and citations would be really great (and if you want to put some explanation in I won't say no)

Comment: Are you talking about ordering independent variables according to how strongly each independent variable correlates to the dependent variable? Or perhaps you are wanting to investigate multicollinearity?

Comment: Thanks for that. Multicollinearity seems to be the best fit (haha) for my problem, as there is no indication that the grouping is dependant on the variables therein; we are looking for a correlation.

Comment: At any rate, are you familiar enough with any statistical software to develop a table of correlations? IF not, try searching online for information about R statistical software (it is free!) and then learning the basics of R (feeding in data etc.) and developing a table of correlations that will show you values for correlation between every possibly pairing of variables. I think this is - roughly - what you want. Hope that helps.

Comment: Ah, I think I may have misunderstood. You see the grouping is actually effectively a variable; however I don't see how it is possible to compare that to anything. The important thing is that I want to have some mechanism that will tell me which variable is the best fit to define that group; in the example above "Shoe size" wold be the best to describe groups A and B, but maybe no others.